# resetting a Swift array causes strong references?

Tags: ios, arrays, automatic-ref-counting

I am getting many low memory warnings, and ultimately a crash in my iOS app.

I have some reason to believe that it has to do with strong/unknown references contained in the data model for a `UICollectionTable`, which is a non-optional Array of non-optional Objects of type `BrowsableRecipe`. I initialize the array as follows:

```
var recipes = [BrowsableRecipe]()
```

where data is a list of `BrowsableRecipe`s returned from an async call from the server.

```
 ServerMessenger.sharedInstance.getRecipesForHomePage(recipeIndex, pageSize: pageSize){ responseObject, error in
  if let data = responseObject{
    //TODO confirm first recipe object doesn't have error param set!

    self.recipes =  data 
    self.recipeIndex = self.recipeIndex + 1
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
      self.collectionView!.reloadData()
    }
  }
```

Where I think the trouble lies is that when I reset the array `self.recipes` to a new list of data, I think that the old array of objects is somehow still maintained or that the points to each `BrowsableRecipe` are somehow still extant in memory. I think it happens here:

```
 self.recipes = data
```

where this is happening after `self.recipes` has been set, and `data` refers to a completely different list of `BrowsableRecipes`. Do I need to go through item in the array and set each `BrowsableRecipe` to `nil`? Also that may result in an error since `BrowsableRecipe` is not an optional.

Comment: What is your "reason to believe" that this is what causing your memory issue?  There isn't anything wrong with the code you've showed and the objects in the array would be released as long as nothing else was holding on to them.

Comment: You don't need to "think"; use the Leaks instrument.

Answer (score 0):

How about first "emptying" the array like so:

```
self.recipes = []
```

or

```
self.recipes.removeAll
```

before `self.recipes = data`?

Comment: This will not affect the memory use of the app. Simply assigning a new array is enough to decrease the reference count and ARC will do its thing.